# Read a line and push into a line-stack until the end of file

Tags: java

I have to do a program and unfortunately I have no idea where to start. It's like we were doing very basic coding and then my teacher went on maternity leave and our substitute thinks we are further along then we actually are. I know how to ready from a file, but I do not know how to put the line into a stack from there.
These are the instructions 
1) Read a line and push into a line-stack until the end of file 2) While line_stack is not empty a. Pop one element out and process the following i. Split elements in this line (i.e. numbers) using StringTokenzier ii. Push all numbers into number-stack iii. While number_stack is not empty 1. Pop a number 2. Print a character using that ascii number

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly you need to:

1. Represent a line as a java.lang.String.
2. Then using [java.util.Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) create a Stack< String> and put all the lines there.
3. Use [java.util.StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to split each line into multiple parts. Each part will be a String itself.
4. Turn each part of the line into a number using Integer.valueOf(String)
5. Put all the numbers into a Stack< Integer>.
6. Print the right character for each number by casting integer value to char.

I think this may be the solution for your problem:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;  

public class LinesProcessor {
  private static Stack<String> readLinesFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Stack<String> lines = new Stack<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)))) {
      String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          lines.push(line);
      }
    }
    return lines;
  }

  private static void processNumbers(Stack<Integer> stackOfNumbers) {
    while (!stackOfNumbers.empty()) {
      Integer number = stackOfNumbers.pop();
      System.out.print((char) number.intValue());
    }
  }

  private static void processLine(String line) {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
    Stack<Integer> stackOfNumbers = new Stack<>();
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {  
      Integer number = Integer.valueOf(tokenizer.nextToken());
      stackOfNumbers.push(number);  
    }
    processNumbers(stackOfNumbers);
  }

  private static void processLines(Stack<String> stackOfLines) {
    while (!stackOfLines.empty()) {
      String currentLine = stackOfLines.pop();
      processLine(currentLine);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.out.println("Name of file missing");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    String fileName = args[0];
    Stack<String> stackOfLines = readLinesFromFile(fileName);
    processLines(stackOfLines);
  }
}
```